# Should I terminate the MII/RMII interfaces?

Tags: ethernet, termination, phy

For Ethernet PHY design, the MDI interface should be terminated. Then how about the MII/RMII or GMII/RGMII interfaces? I've seen some designs terminated them, and most not. There are some PHY chips even advertise they have integrated termination on chip, such as TI's [DP83640](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/dp83640.pdf).

Comment: Well, self-answered? Answer seems to be "read phy and mac manufacturer's data sheets and application notes".

Comment: Some people probably omit the termination if the traces are short and hope for the best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MII runs at 25Mhz, so at that speed transmission line effects are usually not seen. RMII runs at 50Mhz which does need impedance matching and the DP83640 uses 50Ω matching so build your PCB traces for 50Ω if using RMII.

RGMII uses 2.5V CMOS or 1.8V HSTL at 125Mhz

You use HSTL if you have transceivers to do so, this also implies matching

2.5V CMOS will need to have a matched transmission line for whatever port it is being driven from (either microprocessor or FPGA) and the PHY

Answer (score 1):

The requirement for termination in high speed designs is all to do with edge rates and trace length, clock speed isn't important.
Your aim is to have the signal settled with some reasonable margin when it's sampled and in the case of clocks, to have their edges monotonic through switching thresholds, avoiding wobbles that clocked devices could interpret as double clocking.